# R Shiny Picker Input search in named choice header and content

Tags: r, shiny, bootstrap-select, selectinput, pickerinput

I am trying to modify a search bar in `Shiny` such as we can type either the content or his header in `pickerInput`.

Code example :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "pick", label = "Selected", 
    choices = split(c("Choice 1" = "Value 1", "Choice 2" = "Value 2"), c("First", "Other")), 
    multiple = TRUE,
    options = list( `live-search` = TRUE)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This way is would like to type text `Choice 2` or `Other` in search bar and get the second input. But research on `Other` gives no result.

An answer that hide the header but can search on it might be accepted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install development version of {shinyWidgets} (v0.4.9.940, soon on CRAN), you can pass a slot `tokens` in `choicesOpt` to declare some keywords used in live search :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "pick", label = "Selected", 
    choices = split(c("Choice 1" = "Value 1", "Choice 2" = "Value 2"), c("First", "Other")), 
    multiple = TRUE,
    options = list( `live-search` = TRUE),
    choicesOpt = list(
      tokens = c("first choice 1", "other choice 2")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Great add and easy solution ! Unfortunately I have to use current version in use in my professional environment. I keep it in mind for the next release on CRAN.

Comment: It's on CRAN now :)

Comment: a happy combination of circumstances :)